# Access a class from another android project in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to run the demo of this project,

https://android-amazing-listview.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

I imported these projects using Eclipse.

There are two seperate projects in it,

`AmazingListView` and `AmazingListViewDemo` so I downloaded the second one.
However, the files in `AmazingListViewDemo` are creating an object of class     `AmazingListView`, and this class is not present in `AmazingListViewDemo` project, but instead it is available in `AmazingListView` project.

How am I supposed to access the class from another Android project ? please help me

Comment: have a look http://goo.gl/QmFnqs

Comment: First project is a **library project**. If you open **project properties** you'll see a checkbox to declare a project as a **library project**. Classes from library projects in the workspace can be used in the rest of projects.